# GridView xml for layout-large

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

[image]I have the below grid view xml code for layout-large. I have no idea what is the mistake such on device(the screenshot is also there of the device) it is just showing small squares but on studio preview of the xml design it is showing a proper grid view.Kindly help to solve this issue.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="heading"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1050dp"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnWidth="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:rowCount="3">
        <!-- row1-->
        <!--column 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/download"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Download"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- row1-->
        <!--column 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"

            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Status"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!--column 2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Search"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <!-- row2-->
        <!--column 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#176005"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/view1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="View "
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!--column 2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#176005"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/update"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="update"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- row3-->
        <!--column 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#176005"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/register"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Register"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!--column 2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#176005"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/view2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="View "
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!-- row4-->
        <!--column 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#176005"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/calculate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Calculate"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!--column 2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#176005"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/login"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="login"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!-- row5-->
        <!--column 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#176005"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/signup"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="signup"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!--column 2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#176005"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/claim"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Claim"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!-- row6-->
        <!--column 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#176005"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/changepassword"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Change Password"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <!--column 2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sync"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sync"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- row1-->
        <!-- row6-->
        <!--column 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#176005"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/logout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Logout"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly help to solve the above issue please.

Comment: If you are using `ScrollView`, probably you don't need `android:layout_columnWeight.` you should use only `android:layout_rowWeigh` or only `android:layout_weight`.

Comment: I tried that but there is no difference

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted is the file? First of all, it is in-compile-able because you have duplicate ids in some views.

Comment: is it working on small devices?

Comment: @RumitPatel Yes it is working on small devices